# Get connection string and password from Azure management

Tags: c#, sql, azure

I am a user of Azure and want to get a connection string and email password from the azure management portal. I have put these two variables in the app settings and tried to get access to them on my website but the connection string always returns this error: 
**The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.**

Here is my C# code:

```
private string connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SQLAZURECONNSTR_bitverifydb");
private string emailPassword = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPSETTING_Password");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get your connection string and email password in your Azure App Settings by using the **CloudConfigurationManager** class in the **"Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager"** namespace.

Note that you need to install the nuget package for this at the link below.

[Microsoft Azure Configuration Manager](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager/)

The sample code is as below:

```
private string connectionString = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("SQLAZURECONNSTR_bitverifydb");
private string emailPassword = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("APPSETTING_Password");
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion however I still get the same error as before... Does something need to be added to web.config?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have added mentioned keys in your configuration files. You can refer the link below to get familiar with usage of CloudConfigurationManager.
[How to use the CloudConfigurationManager](http://blog.mattmcloughlin.com/how-to-use-the-cloudconfigurationmanager-to-automatically-switch-app-settings/)

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question which Azure platform you are using. Some other answers assumed it's CloudService. However, in a case, you are using AppService, it's the same code as .NET using System.Configuration

```
var connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["bitverifydb"].ConnectionString;
var password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"]
```