# Sensitive Data from Azure Websites

Tags: c#, sql, azure

I want to be able to get a connection string and email password safely from my web app on Azure. I currently have these values stored in my web.config file but understand this is a bad idea for security especially as I plan to opensource my site which would make this option unfeasible.

I am an Azure user and understand that you can access these values from the Azure portal however I am yet to be able to do so as my code fails with this error message:

```
The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.
```

I am using the following code in an attempt to gain access to my password (which is stored in the azure management app settings) and connection string (also available on Azure)

```
private string connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SQLAZURECONNSTR_bitverifydb");
private string emailPassword = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPSETTING_Password");
```

Is something needed in web.config or am I doing something else wrong? How does one access such values from Azure properly?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get connection string and password from Azure management](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35398775/get-connection-string-and-password-from-azure-management)

Answer (score 0):

There was a recent new service called [Azure Key Vault](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/key-vault/) for this kind of scenario.

[Basically](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/key-vault-whatis/), you create and manage the Keys/Secrets on this service and consume them on your apps as URIs.

Here is a [quick guide](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/key-vault-use-from-web-application/) to use it on a .Net Web app.